# Regular Expression finding quotations

Tags: c#, .net, regex

i am trying to check if a string is a quotation with regex in C#.

For e.g.

```
string x = "The flora and fauna of Britain \"has been transported to almost every corner of the globe since colonial times\" (Plants and Animals of Britain, 1942: 8).;    
string y =  "Morris et al (2000: 47) state \"that the debate of these particular issues should be left to representative committees.\"";
```

x and y are two quotations and the regex (or alternative solution) should be able to return true.

I came with this but there is a small problem:

```
string pattern = @"([‘'""]([\w\W]+?)[)])|(([\w\W]+?)[(]([\w\W]+?)[’'""])";
```

Is there any alternatives? Thanks in advance.

The project is an anti-plagiarism web application. The application found that these strings(quotation) was copied from the web. Now assume the user wants not to include these quotations in the search results, the question is how to do it.

The search results are stored in database, i am using EF and linq as such:

var webSearches = _db.WebSearches.Where(x => x.SubmissionId == submissionId).GroupBy(x => x.PlagiarisedText).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).OrderBy(x => x.Id);

I want to filter the result (plagiarisedText) by not including quotations.

Thanks for replies, I appreciate.

Comment: please can you elaborate this question because does not make sense.

Comment: you forgot closing `"` in the first line where you declare string `x`

Comment: could you add the requirements/description for when a string is a quotation?

Answer (score 0):

Use `\\\"`.

Use `Regex.IsMatch()` to find if it contains or not.

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(x, "\\\""));// true if it contains ", otherwise false
```

Comment: Thanks, i need to also to check whether the string contains some (..text here...) which means that the sentence has been quoted.

Answer (score 0):

If `Regex` is not a requirement you can use `String` functions:

```
 int first = str.IndexOf('"');
 int last = str.LastIndexOf('"');
 if (str.Substring(first, last - first) != string.Empty)
 {
      // true
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If it will be true when the first and the end characters are both `"`s, then you can simple use the following regex:

```
".*"
```